# Convert a String into an array List Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a String like this:

```
["http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg", "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg"]
```

How can I convert it into an `ArrayList` of `String`s?

Comment: It looks suspicioulsy like JSON. Is it?

Comment: yes, it comes from a JSON service

Comment: What is the input of your data ?

Comment: Instead of rolling your own parser I'd suggest checking out a library like Jackson, GSON, or Retrofit.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Xhulio check out in my answer what FatalError tried to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more appropriate

```
String jsonArr = "[\"http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg\", 
                   \"http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg\"]";
List<String> listFromJsonArray = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArr);
for(int i =0 ;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
      listFromJsonArray.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
```

And don't forget to add [json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211) library

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ya artifactId json and groupid org.json

Comment: With yours? I don't know. I haven't tested it.

Comment: That is what the OP need to do right as it appears like a json array

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Arrays#asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)

```
String[] stringArray = { "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg", "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg"}
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
```

In case your string contains braces `[]` and double quotes `""`, then you should parse the string manually first.

```
String yourString = "[\"http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg\", \"http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg\"]";
String[] stringArray = yourString
    .substring(1, yourString.length() - 2)
    .replace('"', '\0')
    .split(",\\s+");
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
```

Try the above **if and only if** you will always receive your `String` in this format. Otherwise, use a proper JSON parser library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: The String comes to me from the service as below `["http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg", "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg"]`, now how should I convert into a string without quotations \" .

Comment: @Luigi from the service I get the exact string: `["http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg", "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg"]` Now I want the string to be converted into an arraylist of Strings , and each element to contains this kind of `String` : http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg in order that I could use as an URL. None of your above methods doenst function

Comment: @Xhulio first of all, it's **you** who has to define what you exactly need. Second, we will provide help as far as **what you have asked**. If **you don't ask for it, you won't get that help**. I updated my answer to remove the quotes from the String. Note that it was a small modification to the current code that even you could have done if just put a little effort understanding the code rather than just copying/pasting it and hoping for a miracle to make it work for your specific unknown needs.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be rude to u, I just got confused with the editing the comment. Apparently I gave the wrong impression :(

Comment: @Xhulio you don't look rude to me, but lazy, which I find even worse =\

Comment: as a matter of fact I have been working around your solution since the beginning but my editor, gives me this error like "invalid character" when I use this piece of code `''` . Thats why I posted again before. Thank you for the  compliment by the way, I will keep it in mind :)

Comment: @Xhulio fixed my code. I forgot that the blank character is '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** Iterate through the array and put each element to arrayList on every iteration.

**Method 2:** Use `asList() method`

**Example1:**
Using asList() method

```
String[] urStringArray = { "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17470_500_400.jpg", "http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/17471_500_400.jpg"}
List<String> newList = Arrays.asList(urStringArray);
```

**Example2**
Using simple iteration

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String aString:urStringArray){
newList.add(aString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CSV parser if you remove the first and last brackets ('[',']')

Something like this:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```